# Java error with a while and if statement

Tags: java

Hi I'm new to Java and for my intro class I have to program something that does the following: **Define a problem with user input, user output, While Statement and some mathematical computation.**

What I want to do is have it prompt the user for feet and inches for height, if it's over 5'8 they can't go on the roller coaster; if it's 5'8 or less they can. I realize this would be much easier with like an if else kind of thing but I'm required to use while; also we haven't covered do while yet so I can't use that either. I'm probably messing up horribly and there's some better way to do this, but this is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class coasterHeight
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int feet;
int inches;

System.out.println ("Your must be at least 5'8 to ride this ride.");
System.out.println ("Please enter your height in feet:");

 feet = keyboard.nextInt();
 System.out.println ("Please enter your height in inches:");

 inches = keyboard.nextInt ();



 while (feet <= 5 && inches <= 8)
 {
 System.out.println("You can go on this ride.");
break;
}


 {
 if (feet >= 6 && inches >=9)

 {
 System.out.println ("You cannot go on this ride.");
 }
}
  }


 }
```

So here's the problem. When the input meets the while requirements it works fine (it used to go on an infinite loop with "You can go on this ride" but I discovered break;), but for the if statement, nothing appears in the output. The "You cannot go on this ride", nothing appears, there's no error or anything it just ends the output after I enter a height that is over 5'8. Like I said this is probably awful but any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's the point of a loop if you break immediately?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the problem. You probably want a while loop that repeatedly asks a question until the user exits. This code just throws a while loop in for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `float` or `double` instead, where `float height = 0.00` or `double height = 0.0`.
Then you can use it in the `while` statement such as

```
    while (height >= 5.8){
        System.out.println("You cannot enter the ride");
        break;
    }
    while (height < 5.8){
        System.out.println("You can enter the ride");
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Man I tried something like that before, but thanks bud I understand while a lot better now.

Comment: The comments on the OP still apply - this uses two while loops when none are necessary. You can accomplish the same thing with a simple `if` and it's less code as you would not need the `break`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your program doesn't work as you expect is because your logic is incorrect.

Look carefully at your conditions and think about the different possibilities the user can enter.

`feet <= 5 && inches <= 8`

The and operation `&&` means both parts of this must be true at the same time in order for the statement to evaluate to true. So someone who is 5 feet 9 inches tall would cause this condition to evaluate to false.

The same problem occurs with `feet >= 6 && inches >=9` in that someone who is 7 feet 1 inch tall would cause this condition to evaluate to false.

Also, it seems you have your conditions reversed. At the top of the program you say someone must be at least 5 feet 8 inches in order to go on the ride but then you check for less than that and allow them to go on.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this in pseudo-code (you can fill in the details using what you've already got):

```
while not valid input (not a number, is negative, etc.)
    get height from user

if height allowed on ride
    say "ok"
else
    say "no dice"
```

As another note: notice that `feet <= 5 && inches <= 8` is `true` for (for example) `feet = 7` and `inches = 1`.  I feel they should probably be allowed on the ride.